# Can't get window.scrollTo on hashchange to work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following function to offset by 70 pixels when an anchor is clicked:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 70);
});
```

and it works great in chrome, firefox, and safari, but I can't get it to work in IE. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: It doesn't do anything in IE except make the user double click the link. I've tried in 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        var x = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.html.scrollTop;
        var y = window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.html.scrollLeft;
        window.scrollTo(x, y - 70);
});
```

Remember `window.scrollY` is equivalent to `window.pageYOffset`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this did not work though.

Comment: Is the problem in the hashchange event ?